# Is it possible to clone a Cloud Foundry / Bluemix space? How?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We are using IBM Bluemix PaaS which is based on Cloud Foundry. We have been working in a DEV space for some time and have two apps and a dozen of services. Now we are in the phase of deploying a PROD version which should be very similiar to what we have in DEV. So instead of creating the PROD space manually, that includes creating apps, binding services, loading data etc., is there a easy way, or a CF command, that can allow us to simply clone the DEV space and rename it PROD?

Edit: I have confirmed with some Bluemix experts from within IBM, and it is not possible to clone the entire space. However, pushing apps to multiple spaces is doable using DevOp Build & Deploy or Delivery Pipeline service. Manifest.yml can also help like the comment says below. Services associated to the app will have to be re-created manually in new spaces.

Comment: Are your apps being deployed using a manifest file? https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#appmanifest If you have that part already, deploying to another space should be simpler.

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. It helps. I will use DevOps Build & Deploy to deploy my app this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using the [Delivery Pipeline Service](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy/) on Bluemix.

This allows you to configure automated build, test and deployment stages based on changes to your git repository (or manually triggered).

If you have a pipeline already set up for your dev space you have two options:

1. Change the target space for all of the deploy stages and run them
2. Clone the delivery pipeline to a new project - these can be replicated using a pipeline.yml file. Here is a [sample pipeline configuration file](https://github.com/darcy202/bluemix-ghost/blob/master/.bluemix/pipeline.yml)